# How to add ImageView Component in javaFX on runtime

Tags: javafx

Actually i working on a project where i am stuck in a problemi have need to add a ImageView Component by cliking on a button on the runtime, Any Help? it would be anEventful act of YOur's for helping me.

MainClass

```
public class See extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Controller

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        File fil=new File("src\\see\\unshadedLaptop.png");
        Image im=new Image(fil.toURI().toString());
        ImageView view=new ImageView(im);
        view.prefHeight(200);
        view.prefWidth(200);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        File fil=new File("src\\see\\unshadedLaptop.png");
        Image im=new Image(fil.toURI().toString());
        ImageView view=new ImageView(im);

    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest you Google and read some basic JavaFX/FXML tutorials.

Comment: `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` do not set anything. These calls are simply unneccessary here since those lines just return the size of the image in this case without any side effects. BTW: Of course you need to add the `ImageView`s to the scene...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to give the `Node` an `fx:id` in your `FXML`. Then Do `@FXML YourNodeType yourNodeFxId;`. Then in the `Button` event handler do `yourNodeFxId.getChildren().add(theImageViewHere);`.

Using your code to show an example:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML 
    private Pane pane;//This is just an example. Make sure you have a  Pane with an fx:id="pane" in your FXML.

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        File fil=new File("src\\see\\unshadedLaptop.png");
        Image im=new Image(fil.toURI().toString());
        ImageView view=new ImageView(im);
        pane.getChildren().add(view);//This is the added code.
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Thanks alot sir.